# express js setInterval route 1 and clearInterval route 2

Tags: node.js, express, setinterval

i have a node js server with express js.
On one route i start an interval by using setInterval.
Now i want to stop the interval if a user navigates to a second route.

E.g.

```
router.get('/startInterval', function() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Interval is running');
    }, 1000);
});

router.get('/stopInterval', function() {
    // Stop the interval startet before
    // clearInterval(); <--- How i get the timer object?
});
```

How do i do that?
What is if i declare the timer as a global variable?
Is a second user able to stop the timer started by the first user in a defferent browser?

Comment: Hello, did you solved this in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the timer on the outside scope

```
var timer;

router.get('/startInterval', function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Interval is running');
    }, 1000);
});

router.get('/stopInterval', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

By the way, any user going to the `/stopInterval` route will stop the global timer (ONE timer for ALL users).

If you want to have a different timer for every different user, you'll need way more complicated code (using session, cookie, ...).

Comment: Yes, thats the Problem.
I don't want one global timer. And i don't know how i could save the id from setInterval.